# Selecting the correct "Add" button

Tags: selenium

I have a field that has a "+" Add button in case you want to add more lines. I want to add 2-3 lines with it, then to click on the "+" button from a newly created line to create 2-3 more. The problem is that all buttons are declared the same:

```
<button class="ng-scope" ng-if="formData.order_request_status == STATUSES['OPEN']" ng-click="addImportMaterial()" style="margin-left: 3px;" type="button">+</button>
```

I have written the following xpath:

```
//button[@ng-click='addImportMaterial()']
```

but this selects all plus buttons and I want only the third one to be pressed. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `xpath` with index then as below :-

> I want only the third one to be pressed

```
(//button[@ng-click='addImportMaterial()'])[3]
```

So, (Assuming your using java) use above `xpath` to locate third button and click as :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@ng-click='addImportMaterial()'])[3]")).click()
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I did not know that you can enclose the statement in round parenthesis and just add an index. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be getting a List of buttons, to press the third one you just have to do `buttons.get(2).click();`